# Why does ';' not contain second closing bracket?

Tags: c++, syntax, sdl

I have been working on creating my first game,  (PONG), using C++ and SDL. I have been following a tutorial online and have gotten about half way through. I am now confused from the syntax in the code which also gives me an error. I'm not aware of this use of code.

```
if (Contact contact = CheckPaddleCollision(ball, paddleOne)**;**
                contact.type != CollisionType::None)
            {
                // Ball operates on its own data . ball.CollideWithPaddle/ball.velocity.x
                ball.CollideWithPaddle(contact);
            }
            else if (contact = CheckPaddleCollision(ball, paddleTwo);
                contact.type != CollisionType::None)
            {
                ball.CollideWithPaddle(contact);
            }
```

I do not understand why there is a semicolon before a closing parenthesis. I really don't understand this use of code. I am used to seeing a bool after an if statement. These to if statements do not build for me ; was this a mistake in source code? Any help explaining this code with be of great help.

Source code for the program can be found here.
https://code.austinmorlan.com/austin/pong/src/branch/master/Main.cpp

Comment: This appears to be C++, not C.

Comment: Looks like the writer it working to constrain the scope of `contact`.

Comment: Check the [docs for `if` in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if), especially the 3rd/4th form `attr(optional) if constexpr(optional) ( init-statement(optional) condition ) ...` - in detail described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#If_Statements_with_Initializer)

Comment: Thanks people for all the help. There's a lot more to learn for me in C++.